# Sprite is just visible not totally disappear

Tags: java, android, sprite, andengine

I made a game with andengine.

There are a lot of balls that are moving from point A to point B.

When I touched it, the ball disappeared from the screen, and the score increased by 10 points. However, if I touched the ball (by guessing it's position from the moving path, since I cannot see it anymore), the score will still increase. In other words, the ball only became invisible, but it still exists.

I would like to do an `unregisterTouchArea()` to unregister the ball's touch area.

But I don't know what can I do, do you have any idea?

Comment: You can try `scene.detachChild(ball)` instead of `ball.setVisible(false)`, this will detach the `ball` literally from the `scene` instead of making it invisible only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, you have to unregisterTouchArea and either setVisible(false) or detachChild:

```
mScene.unregisterTouchArea(mBall);
mScene.detachChild(mBall);
```